# Angular Mat-table, Is it possible to update cells individually?

Tags: angular, rxjs, mat-table, formattable

I have a Mat-table where part of the data is updated up to 2 times per second. I have about 3 of these cells in my table whilst the remaining 6 will likely never be updated. Is there a way to update each cell individually as currently by updating the dataSource the entire row updates each time which causes a significant performance drop once I reach somewhere between 6-8 rows (the expected amount of rows for the table is around 10). I have tried using observables as the data and using:

```
{{ element[columnId] | async }}
```

in the cell. This works in that it only updates the number and not the entire row (tested using chrome render debugging). But this breaks the MatSort.
I then tried to override sortingDataAccessor but was unable to get the value since it would require subscribing.

The only solution I could think of although I don't like it is to use BehaviorSubjects for all my data in order to in the sortingDataAccessor use:  `return value.value` to get the value synchronously and then in the template use `element[columnId].asObservable() | async`.

But this to me feels very hacky and I imagine there has to be a better solution to achieve this.